# Distill: Fixing the footer to the bottom of the page

Tags: html, r, r-distill

I have made a website using `Distill` in R but I'm noticing that the footer floats halfway across the page if there's not enough content on it. How can fix the footer to the bottom of every page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding this into your style sheet.

To make a footer fixed at the bottom of the webpage, you could use position: fixed like I have ( Look here ).

```
        #footer {
           
/* Look here*/ position: fixed;
            padding: 10px 10px 0px 10px;
            bottom: 0;
            width: 100%;
            height: 40px;
           
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
footer {
       width: 100%;
       position: fixed;
       bottom: 0;
       left: 0;
       right: 0;
}
```